# Converting .mbtiles to .png images

Tags: qt, maps, openstreetmap, openmaptiles

We are downloaded map.mbtiles from openmaptiles.com.
Now we are tyring to convert that map.mbtiles to png images.
We tried **mbutil** to convert but images we got those are not supported.
We need method or process to convert it.

Comment: can you post the content of a .mbtiles file? is that a kind of vector type?

Comment: yes,it is a kind of vector type

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using the Tileserver-GL to render png raster tiles from your mbtiles. Documentation is avaible here: https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Why would I want to host a conversion through a server? Most people are looking to convert the .mbtiles into a full dump of .png tiles.

Comment: @Dagrooms Because the TS looked for a way to convert vector tiles packed inside a .mbtiles into pngs. If you know of any other software please let us know ;) If your .mbtiles already contains pngs it would be easier but that wasn't asked here.

Comment: I asked that without an understanding of mbtiles. It looks like mbtiles can contain all sorts of different things. Still finding my way around GIS in general but mbtiles is super confusing to a newcomer.